Synchronize react-window list scroll with an external scroll container in React
I'm working on a React application where I need to use react-window to display a list of items. I want to achieve the following:

The list should be scrollable using an external scroll container provided via a scrollContainerRef from a parent component.
The header should remain sticky at the top of the view when scrolling.
The list should properly scroll to show all items, reaching the last item without the list moving out of view.

This is my code so far:
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { UserContext } from 'src/context/UserContext';
import { FixedSizeList as List } from 'react-window';

const ListWithStickyHeader = () => {
    const { scrollContainerRef } = useContext(UserContext);

    const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);
    const listRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsClient(true);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isClient && scrollContainerRef.current && listRef.current) {
            const handleScroll = () => {
                const scrollTop = scrollContainerRef.current.scrollTop;
                listRef.current.scrollTo(scrollTop);
            };

            scrollContainerRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
            return () => {
                scrollContainerRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
            };
        }
    }, [isClient, scrollContainerRef]);

    const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
        <div className="list-item" style={style}>
            Row {index + 1}
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div className="list-wrapper" style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
            <div className="header" style={{ position: 'sticky', top: 0, background: 'white', zIndex: 10 }}>
                Sticky Header
            </div>
            {isClient && (
                <List
                    ref={listRef}
                    height={400}
                    itemCount={30}
                    itemSize={65}
                    width="100%"
                    style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}
                    innerElementType="div"
                >
                    {Row}
                </List>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ListWithStickyHeader;

The list does not scroll down to show the last item; it stops scrolling too early. Also the list window moves away from the page when scrolling down.
How can I correctly synchronise the scroll between react-window list and the parent scroll container using my ref scrollContainerRef?
